# Is HttpClient from WCF REST Starter Kit Silverlight compatible?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, rest

I know in earlier versions of the WCF REST Starter Kit the `HttpClient` class was not usable from Silverlight.  Has that changed?  I did a couple of quick searches and didn't find anything that gave a clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope not the moment .. I heard that they were going to make it compatible on few blogs around the end of the year but that was a while ago.

Marcus

Answer (score 2):

Philipp Sumi has ported it to Silverlight. See [here](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/02/wcf-rest-starter-kit-for-silverlight)